# Ring isomorphism and indempotent element

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring. How to show that $R\cong R_1\times R_2 $, where $R_1,R_2$ are nontrivial rings, if and only if there exist $e\in R,\ e\neq0,1$ such that $e^2=e$ ?

I need only hints.

Comment: $1-e$ is also idempotent, and $e(1-e)=0$. Idempotents are identity elements in $R_1,R_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* $(\Leftarrow)$ Choose $R_1 = Re, R_2 = R(1-e).(\Rightarrow)$ Choose $e = (e_1, 0)$ where $e_i$ is the identity element of $R_i, i = 1, 2.$